# Assembly Language: Read (w/o echo) and write

Tags: assembly

I am writing a program that will read and write characters, converting lowercase characters to uppercase. This is my first assembly program, so I am attempting to first get the program to read in a character and write it out. This is what I have coded so far:

```
    .model      small
    .8086


    .data

lower   db      'a'


    .code

start:
        mov     ax,@data
        mov     ds,ax

        mov     ah,8
        int     21h
        mov     dl,al
        mov     ah,2
        int     21h

exit:
        mov     ax,4c00h
        int     21h
        end     start
```

Have I handled the read/write correctly? When I run this program and enter in a character, I only see one instance of it. Shouldn't it be two? One for the letter I typed, and then one for letter returned? For example, if I type d, I see:

```
d
```

but shouldn't I see:

```
d
d
or
dd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOS Int 08h reads a character from STDIN and does not echo it. If you want to echo the character, call int 01h.

Comment: Thanks. We are not allowed to use echo for this assignment, so I am simply trying to read in a character and then write it to the display. I think I am reading in the character correctly, but if I am writing the character to the display, then shouldn't my program mimic echo? Perhaps there is an error with my write method?

Comment: @raphnguyen: No, you shouldn't see two characters. Your code reads a character, without echo, and then outputs the character. Since you're reading without echo, the character is not being output to the console until you do it. To see what I mean, change the line that reads `mov dl,al` to `mov dl,'X'`. When you run the program, no matter what key you press, it will output `X`.

Comment: Thanks again, Jim. Played around with the program a bit more and have made a lot of progress. I think I understand how it works now.